# DevExpress ASP.NET MVC Combobox not showing the values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, combobox, devexpress-mvc

In my PartialView I add a grid with a column that I need to be a combobox in this way.

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "TheFieldName";
        column.Caption = "ACaption";

        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = ViewData["MyListOfObjects"];
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "Description";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "Description";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(String);
    });
```

The ViewData is populated in the Index method of the Controller and I have checked that it is populated with objects that contain values.

**** EDIT ****
Controller code:

public async Task Index()
    {
        if (TempDataId == null)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "AnotherController");

```
    // If you debug with Visual Studio the ViewData["MyListOfObjects"] is populated 
    ViewData["MyListOfObjects"] = await Worker.GetAllListOfObjects();

    MyViewViewModel myViewViewModel = new MyViewViewModel 
    {
        MyListOne = await Worker.GetAllListOfObjectsWithId(TempDataId),
        MyListTwo = new List<AnotherObject>()
    };

    return View(tipomaViewViewModel);
}
```

The data access Entity Framework Code First method, GetAllListOfObjects:

```
public async Task<List<SimpleObjectEntity>> GetAllListOfObjects()
{
    try
    {

        return await DataContext.SimpleObjectEntities.ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Index View with the Partial GridViews

```
@model Models.ViewViewModel.MyViewViewModel 
@using Internationalization
@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
    ViewBag.Title = Resources.MenuLeftBar;
}
<h4>@Resources.Menu- @Resources.MenuLeftBar</h4>
<div>@Html.Partial("AGridViewPartial", Model.MyListOne)</div>
<br/>
<div>@Html.Partial("AnotherWithComboboxColumnGridViewPartial", Model.MyListTwo)</div>
```

The Combobox in the PopupEditForm not showing anything.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Is "Description" a public get/set property ?

Comment: Yes it is, Entity Framework Code First POCO

Comment: Is your DataSource an `IEnumerable`?  What does the code look like that is populating the ViewData?  Also, a typo on your Caption code.

Comment: Hi, updated my question with all code needed, left the Entities implementation which is plain POCO classes used by Entity Framework and the domain in general.